# Django - Sending Form Data View and Back to template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to capture data from my form and send it to my view so I can do some business logic there.

I have a "booking" website project, I want the user to pick start and end dates( i have a jquery date picker in my template), and on form submit send it to my view (and the db). My view then compares the dates to the prices stored in the database so it knows the price for each day, and on redirect after form submit, data is shown in the website.

Hope that makes sense.

Here is my view:

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)

    unavailable = []
    for start, end in apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date'):
        while start <= end:
            unavailable.append(start.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y'))
            start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()
        date = request.GET.get('reservation.start_date')
        print(date)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking:apartment', kwargs={'apartment_id': apartment.pk}))

    context = {}
    context['form'] = form
    context['apartment'] = apartment
    context['unavailable_dates'] = json.dumps(unavailable)
```

my form:

```py
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'name',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'start_date': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'}),
            'end_date': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker2'}),
        }
```

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn save btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me figure out how can I do this on my own ?
Thank you.

I cant use JS for this.

edit :
models :

```py
class Apartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    apartment_price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ApartmentImages(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="image")
    image = models.ImageField("image")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url



class ApartmentPrices(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="price")
    price_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.apartment.title


class Reservation(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, related_name='reservations',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: everything seems to be correct in the code, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: how can I get the "start_date" and "end_date" values to my template when the user submits the form, I want to display them on redirect. Hope I didnt confuse you haha !

Comment: ok, we usually display the dates before submitting the form right so you have mentioned a JQuery date picker, it does not display the date on HTML page?

Comment: The JQuery picker does display the dates, and user selects the dates with it. 
But after user selects the date  I want to calculate the total price ( each date has it's own price ) and redirect them back to the same page, this time displaying the price too.

Comment: after the post you are redirecting to `booking:apartment` is that and this one the same view?

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Yes, it is the same view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201042/discussion-between-sillenius-and-sammy-j).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have understood the question based on the comments provided. You want to pass the price also onto the HTML page.

You must define global variables as `start_date_price` and `end_date_price` and `context`.

```
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):
    context = {}
    start_date_price = 0
    end_date_price = 0

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)

    unavailable = []
    for start, end in apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date'):
        while start <= end:
            unavailable.append(start.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y'))
            start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()
        date = request.GET.get('reservation.start_date')
        print(date)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            start_date = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
            end_date = form.cleaned_data.get('end_date')

            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()

            # your logic here
            start_date_price = start_date * your_logic
            end_date_price = end_date * your_logic 
            context['start_date_price'] = start_date_price
            context['end_date_price'] = end_date_price

            # I would suggest remove this line and check, when the form renders, it would display all the values there itself
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking:apartment', kwargs={'apartment_id': apartment.pk}))
    context['form'] = form
    context['apartment'] = apartment
    context['unavailable_dates'] = json.dumps(unavailable)
```

Now in the HTML page:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn save btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
 {{start_date_price}}
 {{end_date_price}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort !
Unfortunately I failed to explain it seems, sorry, english is not my native language. I have added my models in hope to make it clearer.

So my end goal is :
Display apartment detail page, user selects dates, gets redirected to the same page, only this time I need to display the price per day, and the total price for those days. I was planning on getting the dates from the form, and then comparing them with the dates from the ApartmentPrices and somehow filter them out with the correct price. So far it's been a battle.